# ESP32 IDF Failed to resolve component 'cxx'

Tags: cmake, clion, esp32, esp-idf

I am not sure what happened but when I reload the cmake it gives me this error.
I am using Clion. should I reinstall esp-idf again ?

-- Component directory C:/Users/shahi/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file. No component will be added

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32
-- Checking Python dependencies...

Python requirements are satisfied.

Skipping the download of C:\Users\shahi.espressif\espidf.constraints.v5.1.txt because it was downloaded recently.

Constraint file: C:\Users\shahi.espressif\espidf.constraints.v5.1.txt
Requirement files:

C:\Users\shahi\esp\esp-idf\tools\requirements\requirements.core.txt
Python being checked:

C:\Users\shahi.espressif\python_env\idf5.1_py3.10_env\Scripts\python.exe

CMake Error at C:/Users/shahi/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:245 (message):
Failed to resolve component 'cxx'.

Call Stack (most recent call first):

C:/Users/shahi/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:281 (__build_resolve_and_add_req)

C:/Users/shahi/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:576 (__build_expand_requirements)

C:/Users/shahi/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:434 (idf_build_process)
CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)

Comment: Make sure that there is a corresponding component folder in the components directory. For example: ESP_IDF/components/<component>.
If your build fails to resolve component "cxx", the folder cxx must be present in the components folder of the ESP_IDF directory. This cxx folder needs to contain its CMakeLists.txt and other files inside.